# Cant spawn custom horse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~1 ~ {Tame:1,Saddle:1,Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:.32},{Name:horse.jumpStrength,Base:1}]}
```

I'm trying to make a custom horse in Minecraft 1.11.2, but it keeps saying "unable to summon object". I'm using the command above, and old commands don't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

In minecraft 1.11.2 it's not `EntityHorse` anymore, but `horse`.

1.11 changed a lot of the entity names, [read up on it here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.11#General_2).